# What is the logical operator I should use in this situation

Tags: javascript, html

This is a test document I made specifically for this question. I am building a JavaScript calculator and I am one problem away from finishing it.

I have two situations. When I press the equals button and the bottom text is:

1. empty/NaN, I need the function to return.
2. 0, I want the function to compute.

When I use the (!bottomtext) operator, it doesn't compute when the zero is at the bottom.

Which operator should I use to disable when it's NaN but work when it's zero ("it" referring to bottomtext)?

Here's my code, keeping in mind that this document was made specifically for this question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        function displayNum(x) {
            document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML += x;
        }

        function chooseOperation(x) {
            if (document.getElementById('top') !== '') {
                compute();
            }
            document.getElementById('operation').innerHTML = x;
            transferText();
        }

        function clearNum2() {
            document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = "";
        }

        function transferText() {
            if (document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML !== '') {
                document.getElementById('top').innerHTML = document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML;
            } else {
                return;
            }
            clearNum2();
        }
        function compute() {
            var result;
            var uppertext = parseInt(document.getElementById('top').innerHTML);
            var operation = document.getElementById('operation').innerHTML;
            var bottomtext = parseInt(document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML);
            console.log("uppertext =", uppertext, "|", typeof (uppertext))
            console.log("operation =", operation, "|", typeof (operation))
            console.log("bottomtext =", bottomtext, "|", typeof (bottomtext))
            console.log("equation is", uppertext, operation, bottomtext)
  // my problem is here
            if (bottomtext = NaN) {
                return;
            } else {
                switch (operation) {
                    case ('+'):
                        result = uppertext + bottomtext;
                        break;
                    case ('-'):
                        result = uppertext - bottomtext;
                        break;
                    case ('*'):
                        result = uppertext * bottomtext;
                        break;
                    case ('/'):
                        result = uppertext / bottomtext;
                        break;
                    default:
                        return
                }
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
                console.log("result =", result, "|", typeof (result))
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Refresh to Reset</h1>
    <h2>Open console</h2>
    <h2>Clear console after pressing the multiplication button for clearer results</h2>
    <h2>Multiply 1 by 0 and press equals</h2>
<hr>
<h3>Top</h3>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <h3>Operation</h3>
    <div id="operation"></div>
    <h3>Bottom</h3>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
    <h3>Result</h3>
    <div id="result"></div>
<hr>
    <button onclick="displayNum(1)">1</button>
    <button onclick="displayNum(0)">0</button>
    <button onclick="chooseOperation('*')">Multiply</button>
    <button onclick="compute()">=</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "bottom text?"

Comment: It is the text at the bottom, which is the second number in the equation.

Comment: @AskYous Probably the variable named `bottomtext` ;-P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `bottomtext = NaN` is an assignment, you should use `isNan(bottomText)`

Comment: `if (bottomtext = NaN) {` this is an assignment op not comparison, if you want to test for `NaN` use `isNaN(...)`

Comment: you need to `isNaN` to check if variable is number or not.

Comment: Note that `NaN != NaN` and `NaN !== NaN`, which is why everyone is telling you to use `isNaN`. See more [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).